# Spring Boot set response headers on single endopint

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, controller

I try to add a response header to a singel endopoint.

This is my controller class.

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dds/users")
public class TypeController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @GetMapping()
    public List<UserFullDto> getAll() {
        return userService.getAll().stream().map(userMapper::mapToFullDto).toList();
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to add a response header without making the methode return a `ResponseEntity<>`

I dont want to use this this:

```java
@GetMapping()
public ResponseEntity<List<UserFullDto>> getAll() {
    var users = userService.getAll().stream().map(userMapper::mapToFullDto).toList();
    return new ResponseEnity.ok().header().body(users);
}
```

I have tried this without succes (gives me a 404)

```java
@GetMapping(headers = "Cache-Control=max-age=3600")
public ResponseEntity<List<UserFullDto>> getAll() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without ResponseEntity. Change the signature of your class to

```
@GetMapping()
public public List<UserFullDto>getAll(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
```

And than you can use `response.addHeader(name, value)`

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps!

Response entity is overloaded with several arguments, for better readability, you can create a modular method which creates and returns this `Map` so it can be re-used.

```
MultivaluedMap<String,String> responseHeaders =new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
responseHeaders.add("content-type","application/json");
responseHeaders.add("somethingElse","value");
return new ResponseEntity<>(users, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: Thx for responding, but as stated in my question i dont want to return a `ResponseEntity` in my method. Is it plausible?

Comment: You either have `ResponseEntity` or any native type such as String, Integer, Boolean , List<String> List<Object> etc, however, ResponseEntity can wrap your native type or objects with additional information such as status code and response headers , so it is advised to use that